# Custom column in Custom SQL on BigQuery

Tags: sql, parameters, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm stacking on some issue on Tableau when I'm trying to run Custom query with string parameter. I'd like to query one column dynamically from certain table on BigQuery.
My SQL looks like.:

```
select  <Parameters.column for research> as column,
        count(*) as N
from table_name
where date=<Parameters.date>
group by 1
```

Here I'm trying to use parameter as column name.
But unfortunatlly I'm receive string column with one value of the parameter.

[image]

Is it possible to execute my request? If it's doable, so how to write the Custom SQL?

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de) it approaches a similar situation with the use of "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE" at the end just use Bigquery [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries)  and it shoudl do the work

Comment: Posting it as a comments since I'm not sure I understood the issue correctly